# eglCreateWindowSurface set an X position

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, surface, egl

I'm using opengles to create my own display on Android.
I have one monitor and I want to display two surfaces on it (the first is Android and the second is my own display).

Note : Monitor resolution is (1920x1080)

For that I have been able to set a custom size to my Android System UI on the left (1280x1080). So I have now a free space at right (840x1080) to other display.
I was able to create a green surface with this resolution (840x1080), problem is that it goes on the left so it hides the Android system. I would like to applicate a translation of 1280 px on it so it goes on the right side.

Here is my code :

```
const EGLint attribs[] = {
            EGL_RED_SIZE,   8,
            EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL_BLUE_SIZE,  8,
            EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
            EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLint w, h;
    EGLint numConfigs;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLSurface surface;
    EGLContext context;

    EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

    eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);
    eglChooseConfig(display, attribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);
    if ((surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, s.get(), NULL)) == EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
    ALOGD("initSurface() eglCreateWindowSurface failed");
    return;
    }
    context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, NULL);
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w);
    eglQuerySurface(display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h);
    ALOGD("Surface size is w = %d h = %d", w, h);

    if (eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context) == EGL_FALSE) {
    ALOGD("initSurface() eglMakeCurrent failed");
        return ;
    }

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glDisable(GL_DITHER);
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    eglSwapBuffers(display, surface);
```

What is the function I need to applicate this translation with opengles ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with EGL itself; EGL simply creates surfaces which can be used by both OpenGL ES and the display subsystem.

Actually creating the window into which that surface can be placed is a native operation of the host operating system; it has nothing to do with EGL really and is handled by OS-specific code on every platform.

Android isn't really designed to have "windows" in the traditional sense, so I'm not even sure if this is possible using Android APIs. There are proprietary solutions here - like Samsung's split screen mode - but I don't think they are exposed to the application API other than as a window resize event.

Comment: Even with a shader program or some matrice operation ? What if I create a fullScreen surface with a transluscent part to make Android visible  and the other part with a custom view ?